# Is there a way to create a non-stop spinning square using html and css?

Tags: html, css

I want to create a non-stop spinning square using html and css. I currently have:

```
@-webkit-keyframes spinnow {
    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes spinnow {
    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
@-ms-keyframes spinnow {
    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

What I have currently got will make the square spin, but it will always stop after one full rotation, then start shortly afterwards. How do I make it continuously spin without stopping?

N.B. I'm using @-webkit-keyframes, @-moz-keyframes and @-ms-keyframes.

Thanks very much,

Lucas

Comment: What HTML and CSS code do you have so far?

Comment: I just added it in as an edit. Thank you for reminding me to add that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the *definition* of the animation, but with its *usage*:

```
.foo {
    animation: 5s spinnow infinite linear;
}
```

The `infinite` keyword is what you need. You can also put an integer there, to have a finite number of rotation cycles.

**Edit by OP:** For future visitors, the `linear` keyword is to make the animation not speed up and then slow down using the swing animation, but rather use a linear, smooth approach, so that the speed is distributed and does not make the square appear to stop. This keyword was the important one for me - I had the `infinite` keyword already.

http://jsfiddle.net/GXPS8/

Comment: Can you please rewrite your jsfiddle code? When I clicked the link, all I saw was a stationary square. Sorry for bothering you.

Comment: Right now it's not spinning on chromium, works in firefox
Just a minor problem in the order of parameters
http://jsfiddle.net/ZD7yN/ this one works

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the existing code goes through rotation of 360 degrees, then 0 degrees, then rotates back to 360 degrees again.

The stop you perceive may be due to the animation rendering the same rotation twice (360 degrees = 0 degrees).

**EDIT**: not pure HTML+CSS as OP is trying to do, but it may address the fluidity issue.

Calculating the amount of rotation to do via a formula similar to this should do the trick:

```
var rotation=0;
...
function _RotateStep(){
    rotation=(rotation+1)%360;
    //apply rotation to element (via method of choice)
    setTimeout("_RotateStep()",250); //or time between rotation steps of your choice
}
```

In Pure CSS, you may be able to get away with setting it to rotate to 359 degrees continuously, eliminating the duplicate rotation being rendered.

Comment: nah, javascript's ok. Thanks!